# C# - Program execution flow yield/pause/resume

Tags: c#, execution, yield, resume

Could you tell me please if there is a way in C# to pause and resume the program execution flow as I would like to do below?

Or do you have an idea how to save/load the current thread call stack?

I am looking for a solution that does not creates new thread at all.

```
public class MyClass : InterruptableClass
{
    int x;

    public void Fn1()
    {
        x = 1;
        this.Interrupt();
        x = 2;
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();

        c.Fn1();
        // Now c.x is 1

        if (c.IsInterrupted)
        {
            c.ResumeExecution();
            // Now c.x is 2
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot save / reload the call stack (StackTrace/StackFrame).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into threads and thread synchronization using Events or Locks, depending on which is appropriate for your scenario.

You can tell a thread to wait for other threads or to wait until some event happens using these mechanisms, so that while it is actually waiting it will most likely (depending on OS) be context switched out, so other threads having work to do, can actually get on with work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at `await` keyword that will be introduced in the next version of C#.

If you need the solution now, consider using TPL continuations (`Task.ContinueWith` method).

Comment: You are right, but TPL uses new threads. I need a solution that does not requires new thread to be created.